# The derivation of the Weierstrass elliptic function

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, elliptic-curves, book-recommendation, elliptic-functions

I am wondering if any of you could point me to any books and/or lecture notes that explain the Weierstrass $\wp$ function for a self-studying student of elliptic curves and functions. I am interested in any resources that may give the history of the Weierstrass function and its derivation. I do understand the basics of lattices and doubly-periodic functions, but I am having trouble seeing the thought process that led to the creation of the function itself. I have tried searching through many books and while I have found several good ones, I haven't yet found one that shows the thought process that led to the Weierstrass $\wp$ function. (Sorry, but I am not sure how to format the letter that is traditionally associated with this function).

What resources are there to understand the derivation of $\wp$?

Comment: Put \wp(z) enclosed by the sign of dollar as usual and you will get $\wp(z)$

Comment: I think that "the thought process that led to the Weierstrass ℘ function." was in the mind of Weierstrass over a long time with peculiar pathways. What do you really want to know? Please reformulate your question more specifically about what it is you don't understand. The function already exists. Why the concern over "the thought process that led to the Weierstrass ℘ function"?

Answer (score 7):

HINT: here I give you a brief note, hoping that something you can help.

Knowing that all $L$-elliptic function (i.e. meromorphic and $L$-periodic) must have a finite order at least equal to $2$, the function $\wp$ gives a solution to the problem of construct a $L$-elliptic function taking exactly this minimum of twice all complex value $u$ in all fundamental parallelogram $P$ for the lattice $L$.

Assuming that such a function exists, it can have either just one pole of order 2 or two simple poles (two distinct kinds of these functions!); both exist in fact, the first one with a pole of order two are the $L$-functions $\wp$ of Weierstrass and the second one, the elliptic functions of Jacobi with two simple poles. The first function is defined by
$$\wp(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{\omega\in L\setminus\{0\}}\left[\frac{1}{(z-\omega)^2}-\frac{1}{\omega^2}\right]$$
(*a simpler form with $\sum \frac{1}{(z-\omega)^2}$ is useless because it is not convergent and the variation shown in $\wp$ has no other purpose than to ensure the necessary convergence*).

If $P$ is the fundamental parallelogram of vertices $0,\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_1+\omega_2$, the values $\wp(z_0)$ for $z_0=0,\frac{\omega_1}{2},\frac{\omega_2}{2},\frac{\omega_1+\omega_2}{2}$ are taken just once because $z_0$ is in each case a point of order two in $P$ (*this because $0$ is a double pole with residue zero and the other three are double points since $\wp’=0$ and $\wp’’\ne 0$*). All the other points $z\in P$ are simple and for all complex value $u\ne \wp(z_0)$ one has $\wp(z_1)=\wp(z_2)=u$ for certain unique $z_1$ and $z_2$ in $P$ which either are symmetric respect to $\frac {\omega_1+\omega_2}{2}$ (*in whose case $z_1$ and $z_2$ are interior points of $P$*) or are symmetric respect to $\frac{\omega_k}{2}$; $k=1,2$ (*in whose case $z_1$ and $z_2$ are in the boundary of $P$, in the two sides assigned to $P$*)

[image]

►$\wp(z)$ has a derivative $\wp’(z)$ which is odd of order three and all $L$-elliptic function belongs to the field $\mathbb C(\wp, \wp’)$ of rational expressions of $\wp(z)$ and $\wp’(z)$ with complex coefficients; this field is a quadratic extension of the field $\mathbb C(\wp)$ formed by all the even $L$-elliptic functions.

►$\wp$ and $\wp’$ are transcendental functions but are not algebraically independent and it is verify that $$(\wp’)^2=4\wp^3-g_2 \wp-g_3$$ where the called invariants of $\wp$ are defined by $$g_2=60\sum_{\omega\in L\setminus\{0\}}\frac{1}{\omega^4}$$ and $$g_3=140\sum_{\omega\in L\setminus\{0\}}  \frac{1}{\omega^6}$$
Besides one has an “addition theorem” given by $$\wp(u+v)=\frac 14\left[\frac{\wp’(u)-\wp’(v)}{\wp(u)-\wp(v)}\right]^2-\wp(u)-\wp(v)$$
These two equalities allow us go from the transcendent to algebraic and this is the link between the elliptic functions and the cubic curves of genus 1.

Comment: @Bumblebee: Thank you very much for the English correction (I need it). This answer of mine was extracted from my book in Spanish "Invitation to the study of arithmetic of elliptic curves" (literal translation of the title) that resulted from a course that I taught at the VI Summer Mathematical School in Venezuela some years ago. This was in large part what I argued for in my PhD thesis in France.

Comment: It is a somewhat unfortunate that the theory of elliptic functions is not a part of standard curriculum anymore while its descendants are still highly active research topics such as elliptic curves, Modular forms, abelian varieties, formal group laws, etc.

Comment: I agree dear friend. However, it should be emphasized that this fascinating branch of mathematics is quite sophisticated and its study is "difficult". What should not go without affirming that in the future it will be "easy". Question of cultural times.

Comment: OP asked "point me to any books and/or lecture notes that explain". - Which sources did you use while studying elliptic functions?

Comment: @nilo de roock: I am sorry, dear friend, but everything that you have seen in some detail in this post I have taken from my book in Spanish "Invitation to the study of elliptic curves arithmetic" (for my doctoral thesis in France I had to consult a lot of documentation mainly in specialized magazines). In any reference on elliptic curves (even on the internet) you will find bibliography about it but without minute details.

Comment: Thank you, @Piquito

Comment: You are welcome, Nilo.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late but I was also stuck at finding references for the construction of the Weierstrass p function while reading [1] and here is what I ended up with.

- [1] and [Prof. Borcherds](https://youtu.be/p1dts9PrDtI?t=136) discuss for $\omega \in \Omega$ where $\Omega$ is a fundamental parallelogram representing a set of periods of a meromorphic function, $\sum_{\omega \in \Omega} \frac{1}{(z - \omega)^2}$ is not convergent (e.g., Theorem 3.9.2 of [1]) so they subtracted the residual part (See Prof.'s video), $\frac{1}{\omega^2}$, giving us $\sum_{\omega \in \Omega} \frac{1}{(z - \omega)^2} - \frac{1}{\omega^2}$. But, $\omega = 0$ for this series blow-up so we take this case out of the series by going back to the form of $\frac{1}{(z - \omega)^2}$ with $\omega = 0$, which leaves us $\frac{1}{z^2} + \sum_{\omega \in \Omega - {0}} \frac{1}{(z - \omega)^2} - \frac{1}{\omega^2}$.
- [Lecture note from Harvard Math 213 a](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Esiu/math213a/elliptic_function_weierstrass_approach_part1.pdf) discusses the use of Taylor polynomial in the section "Partial Fraction Expansion of Weierstrass p Function" though I couldn't quite follow it...

Hope this helps you or someone!

### Reference

[1] Jones, Gareth A., and David Singerman. Complex functions: an algebraic and geometric viewpoint. Cambridge university press, 1987